# How to get rid off default css styles

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I have installed html5 blank template and I have created sub theme too by creating `style.css` and `functions.php`. But how should I get rid off default CSS styles that come from parent theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two ways, 
first: if you want to remove default style, just dequeue them using  `wp_dequeue_style( 'style_file_name_here' )`.
second: you can rename the existing file and create a new one with the same name, just place style hook info into new style file, like:

```
/*
Theme Name: Theme name
Author: Author name
*/
```

remember, the second way is unprofessional, but you can use this one as well.

Comment: I am new to wordpress, can u please tell me where should I write `wp_dequeue_style('style.css')`?in my functions.php for sub theme?

Comment: write down this piece of code into your function.php.
for more help, you can look into this [link](http://wpsites.net/web-design/how-to-deregister-dequeue-style-sheets/)

Answer (score -2):

Go to the parent theme's functions.php and remove any enqueued styles you don't want.

Comment: Thanku @tejas, but is this the right way?

Comment: You lose updatability by doing that. Haris answer is the right way to go.